# How to programatically determine the color of the text in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Basically as the question in a title. How may I check what is the actual color of the text in a TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use

```
mTextView.getCurrentTextColor();
```

For more information see the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCurrentTextColor%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

getResources().getColor(R.color.idname);

check this link for more info:

http://sree.cc/google/android/defining-custom-colors-using-xml-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however my question was to get color of the text, not set it.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.getCurrentTextColor();
```